pySpark - each executor showing my total data size in spark UI
I have executed pySpark code with  25 executors and each executor having 2 GB RAM with 1 core.my total data file size is 293 GB. The pySpark code is reading the data file of 293 GB size and doing some minor transformations and write to Hive table.
When I look into spark UI - in "stage" tab, I could see each executor is getting my total size of the file. why is it so ? can anyone explain ? please find below screenshots.



It will help if you can post the code that you are executing.
I could think one reason where it might happen, if in your code you are doing inferSchema for each partition then each executor will read whole data to get the schema.
Same way if your code is doing some table level count for each partition then also executor will read whole data, hence the UI shows that.

that's right. i am doing infer schema and count operation on dataframe. Is there any way to optimize that ?

You can move the inferschema at central level, rather than at each partition.

I use df = spark.read.parquet('filePath'). could you please let me know what you mean by central level?

It is hard to tell from a single line of code, please update the question description with the full code.
